# ASP.NET Bundling: Run IBundleTransform even when not optimizing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-optimization

We're using `System.Web.Optimization` bundling to bundle & compress our JS and CSS.

We also use a custom `IBundleTransform` implementation in addition to to the existing `JsMinify` and `CssMinify` to do some fancy stuff to the JS (replacement of certain placeholders) before sending it to the browser.

Everything works fine as long as we're running in Release mode, because then the bundling and optimizing kicks in. But in Debug mode (which is nice for debugging ;) it seems to completely ignore all the specified `IBundleTransform` (makes sense in most use-cases, I guess).

Is there any way to *always* run our own `IBundleTransform`, even in Debug mode, but run the other (default) bundling algorithms (`JsMinify`, `CssMinify`) only when I really want to optimize (in Release mode)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the debug/release magic is controlled via the Scripts/Styles helpers.  The behavior to not apply any transforms is baked into the implementation of these helpers, so if you want to do this, the best workaround might just be to have a debug/release version of each bundle and always enable bundling via BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true.

Comment: Tx, I'll go with your suggestion/workaround and create specialized `Debug` and `Release` bundles.`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

Comment: Tx, but this does not solve the problem, because I don't need to change Debug-/Release-mode, but I need to use Release-mode features in Debug-mode.